# Create tensor with random index to be zero

Tags: python, tensorflow

Now I have a tensor `random_row`, and I want to create a new tensor, whose shape is known 2-dim, and its `random_row` to be all zeros, and all other rows to be all ones, e.g.

```py
random_row = [1, 3]  # random_row is a tensor itself

# new_tensor needs to be another tensor whose row in random_row to be all zeros
# we already know new_tensor's shape to be (4, 2)
new_tensor = [[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0]]
```

How can I achieve that? Really appreciate it if someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a function like his:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def zero_rows(x, idx)
    # Turn row indices into a boolean mask
    n = tf.shape(x)[0]
    m = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(idx, 1), tf.ones_like(idx, dtype=tf.bool), [n])
    # Select zeros where the indices are or the data elsewhere
    return tf.where(m, tf.zeros_like(x), x)

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    y = zero_rows(x, idx)
    print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], idx: [1, 3]}))
    # [[1 2]
    #  [0 0]
    #  [5 6]
    #  [0 0]]
```